# Memory-efficient sparse array in Java

Tags: java, memory, sparse-array

(There are some questions about time-efficient sparse arrays but I am looking for memory efficiency.)

I need the equivalent of a `List<T>` or `Map<Integer,T>` which

1. Can grow on demand just by setting a key larger than any encountered before. (Can assume keys are nonnegative.)
2. Is about as memory-efficient as an `ArrayList<T>` in the case that most of the indices are not `null`, i.e. when the actual data is not very sparse.
3. When the indices are sparse, consumes space proportional to the number of non-`null` indices.
4. Uses less memory than `HashMap<Integer,T>` (as this autoboxes the keys and probably does not take advantage of the scalar key type).
5. Can get or set an element in amortized log(N) time where N is the number of entries: need not be linear time, binary search would be acceptable.
6. Implemented in a nonviral open-source pure Java library (preferably in Maven Central).

Does anyone know of such a utility class?

I would have expected Commons Collections to have one but it did not seem to.

I came across `org.apache.commons.math.util.OpenIntToFieldHashMap` which looks almost right except the value type is a `FieldElement` which seems gratuitous; I just want `T extends Object`. It looks like it would be easy to edit its source code to be more generic, though I would rather use a binary dependency if one is available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would try with [trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/) collections, there is [TIntObjectMap](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/) which can work for your intents.

Comment: That looks good. I tried adapting `OpenIntToFieldHashMap` to a generic value type, which seems to have worked with ~10min work, but it only performs marginally better than `TIntObjectMap`.

Answer (score 5):

I would look at Android's SparseArray implementation for inspiration. You can view the source by downloading AOSP's source code here http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android-source-browsing/source/browse/core/java/android/util/SparseArray.java?spec=svn.platform--frameworks--base.58aff7debfdab8ca99dd6bfcfa0c7bebdf2d303b&repo=platform--frameworks--base&r=58aff7debfdab8ca99dd6bfcfa0c7bebdf2d303b does look to be appropriate—amortized run time is undocumented but from inspection I am guessing it is logarithmic—and is under ASL 2.0, which is fine. Unfortunately it is not in Central that I know of, and would want it decoupled from unrelated stuff like Android Bluetooth support which is all in the same source root.

Comment: Here's a self contained version that uses all the necessary code from android

https://github.com/frostwire/frostwire-jlibtorrent/blob/b4b3f9a90d7a1dade864d7e3eaa88b616f200a9a/src/com/frostwire/jlibtorrent/SparseArray.java

Comment: You might be looking more precisely for `SparseIntArray` where you avoid costs of boxing/unboxing the indexes https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseIntArray And yes source code is available and easy+friendly license if you want to extract it from the google code base and adapt it.

Answer (score 1):

I have saved my test case as [jglick/inthashmap](https://github.com/jglick/inthashmap). The results:

```
HashMap size: 1017504
TIntObjectMap size: 853216
IntHashMap size: 846984
OpenIntObjectHashMap size: 760472
```

Comment: Where do I find IntHashMap?

Comment: @oleh probably apache commons (?)

Comment: Sorry, `IntHashMap` was my adaptation of `OpenIntToFieldHashMap` from Commons Math. Since it was barely better than `TIntObjectMap` I dismissed this approach.

Comment: @JesseGlick see http://java.dzone.com/articles/time-memory-tradeoff-example and https://gist.github.com/leventov/bc14ea790b4d3cfd238d#file-memory-txt

Comment: @leventov interesting. Addresses a different set of questions than I was asking here but a good source to investigate potential implementations.

Comment: Why different. It shows average relative memory overuse of "int -> int" maps in libraries, that correlates with "int -> obj" well because specializations are homogenuous within all libs.

Comment: Well, you are also measuring access speed which I was not considering relevant (so long as it is logarithmic); and my memory comparison is to a non-sparse `ArrayList<T>`, which would be half the size of the “theoretical minimum” in the more general case you were considering.

Comment: In your answer only different hash table implementations are compared. I referenced another comparison, which include all impls you tested, and more.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to use OpenIntObjectHashMap from Colt library. [Link](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It does indeed have moderately but significantly lower space consumption than the alternatives. I have included this in my revised test case.

Answer (score 0):

Late to this question, but there is [IntMap](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/IntMap.java) in libgdx which uses [cuckoo hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_hashing). If anything it would be interesting to compare with the others.