# How do I make a large 3D array without running out of memory?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, out-of-memory, bigdata

I have the following method:

```
public static void createGiantArray(int size) {
    int[][][] giantArray = new int[size][size][size];
}
```

When I call it with a size of 10,000 like so:

```
createGiantArray(10000);
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

How can I create an array that is 10,000 x 10,000 x 10,000 while bypassing the memory exception?

(I am aware my current method is pointless and loses scope.  I didn't post the extra code that goes with it.)

Comment: You can either change your array type for a more dynamic type (to increase only when needed) or  increase your java memory changing the execution parameters e.g. Xmx and Xms values

Comment: Just as a side note: `10,000^3 == 1,000,000,000,000`, i.e. ~ `931 GB` of memory. Really?

Comment: @dhke Exactly my thoughts, and each integer is 4bytes, so its 931 * 4 GB actually!

Comment: is it any reason why you need so big array? what you are using it for? can you refactor it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is going to be relatively sparse, then you can use a different data structure, like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390181/sparse-matrices-arrays-in-java) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626135/memory-efficient-sparse-array-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're realising that a 3 dimensional array of 10,000 by 10,000 by 10,000 integers (4 bytes each) amounts to 3725Gb! You can increase your heap size with the `-Xmx` flag, but that amount is still humungous.

You need to change the design of your program.

Comment: The problem was intended to be memory intensive.  I am trying to create a problem which needs to be solved.  But I did not mean to make it that intensive.  Thanks!

Comment: It's even worse, because it's a 3d-array of ints so there would need to be room for the object pointers for the sub-arrays of ints, too.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can't mantain in memory a structure of that dimension.
Each int occupy 4 bytes.
So you have 10.000 x 10.000 x 10.000 x 4 bytes = **4.000.000.000.000 bytes** that is around **4 terabyte**. 
You need to mantain your data on a database (quite big database) and access them as needed.
A secondary possibility is to mantain the data in a distributed memory system like a distributed hashtable over many servers. For example 4000 servers with 1 gigabyte of ram.