# Java : Simple array with custom range of values (int)?

Tags: java, arrays

i have the following code;

```
int minValForRange = myDataObj.getMinValue();
            int maxValForRange = myDataObj.getMaxValue();

            String[] arrOfRangesForSelection = new String[maxValForRange];

            Logger.d(String.valueOf(minValForRange));
            Logger.d(String.valueOf(maxValForRange));

            for (int i = minValForRange; i <= maxValForRange; i++) {
                arrOfRangesForSelection[i] = String.valueOf(i);
            }
```

minValForRange & maxValForRange are dynamic variables (in this case are 1 and 300) so it this case code above is throwing exception:

```
 length=300; index=300
```

How to have an array which is indexed from minValueRange please?

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: you need to have array of size maxvalue + 1 so it will have max value as index

Comment: Another take on your requirement could be to use some sort of Map style collection. There's an interesting discussion, and some suggested solutions, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626135/memory-efficient-sparse-array-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

> How to have an array which is indexed from minValueRange please?

You can't, in Java. Your best bet is just to do the math as necessary (but I mention a couple of alternatives below, which really just encapsulate it), e.g.:

```
int minValForRange = myDataObj.getMinValue();
int maxValForRange = myDataObj.getMaxValue();

String[] arrOfRangesForSelection = new String[maxValForRange - minValForRange + 1];
// Enough room for the range (inclusive) -----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Logger.d(String.valueOf(minValForRange));
Logger.d(String.valueOf(maxValForRange));

for (int i = minValForRange; i <= maxValForRange; i++) {
    arrOfRangesForSelection[i - minValForRange] = String.valueOf(i);
    // The math ------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

*(Note that in the above I'm assuming `maxValForRange` **should** be included, because that's how you wrote your loop, which is why we have `+ 1` in the line allocating the array.)*

If you *didn't* want `maxValForRange` to be included (in programming, we usually include the lower bound but not the upper bound), you wouldn't have the `+ 1` on the array allocation and would use `<` rather than `<=` in the loop:

```
int minValForRange = myDataObj.getMinValue();
int maxValForRange = myDataObj.getMaxValue();

String[] arrOfRangesForSelection = new String[maxValForRange - minValForRange];
// No + 1 here --------------------------------------------------------------^

Logger.d(String.valueOf(minValForRange));
Logger.d(String.valueOf(maxValForRange));

for (int i = minValForRange; i < maxValForRange; i++) {
// Just < here ----------------^
    arrOfRangesForSelection[i - minValForRange] = String.valueOf(i);
}
```

---

If you want, you can trivially write a class that will provide `get` and `set` methods which do the necessary math so you don't have to repeat it all over the code, and wrap your array in that class.

You can also do an `ArrayList` subclass that does the necessary math.

Comment: I don't understand you math. OP confused by seeing the output `length=300; index=300` in the stacktrace.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ: The primary question, as I see it, is *"How to have an array which is indexed from minValueRange please?"* That said, I *also* addressed the issue of making sure the array is large enough for both bounds to be included.

Comment: Better than doing the math "inline" like that, is to encapsulate the array in a class.

Comment: @aioobe: Yes, I mentioned that from the outset (see the end). It depends, of course, on the scope of the array. If it were **only** the quoted code, a class would be overkill. But if there's more to it (and there probably is), I'd encapsulate.

Answer (score 0):

Access to array element is zero-based, so when you try to access maxValForRange, you have to have maxValForRange+1 size;

Answer (score 0):

just use i < maxVal instead of i <= maxVal.

```
for (int i = minValForRange; i < maxValForRange; i++)
    arrOfRangesForSelection[i] = String.valueOf(i);
```