# Create a matrix

Tags: java, arrays, size

Creating a matrix of size[15088][15088][5] in java runs me out of heap space using int as a datatype. How would I create one? Using the command -Xmx did not help.

```
int[][][] a=new int[15088][15088][5];
```

Comment: can't you use any other data type? like bitset, etc.

Comment: @nithin kumar this is very big array it requires more than 4gb ram.

Answer (score 2):

If you use 15088 * 15088 * 5 size of array, then the array needs **15088 * 15088 * 5 * 4 bytes = 4.24 GB**(approximately)** **of heap size**. If the data is sparsely distributed then you could use other data structures like described in the following references.

[Memory-efficient sparse array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626135/memory-efficient-sparse-array-in-java)

Comment: You to use OpenIntObjectHashMap from Colt library, which needs significantly lower memory, when compared to other alternatives.

Comment: How do you create an arrays of array using list or hash set ?