# How to create a 100kx100k Matrix in Hack Reactor using Java language?

Tags: java

I want to create a 100k x 100k matrix in java. The code is going to be execute in an online editor (Hack Reactor), so I can't increase heap size. I found somewhere that I can use SparseMatrix, but in this online editor I can't import the jars of SparseVector. So can you help to solve the problem? Should I use multi threading?

Comment: 100k x 100k of `int` objects is something like `40GB` worth of memory, why do you need this big of an array?

Comment: How multithreading related to memory problem?

Comment: Try some of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626135/memory-efficient-sparse-array-in-java

Comment: @Mark I need to create this big array because it is part of a job test.

Comment: You're not being consistent. If you need an array, then you can also not use SparseMatrix

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map` as sparse matrix.

Just create class `Pair` and use it as key.

```
class Pair {
     final int x;
     final int y;
     Pair(int x, int y) {
         this.x=x;
         this.y=y;
     }

     public boolean equals(Object o) {
          Pair other = (Pair)o;
          return x==other.x&&y==other.y;
     }
     public int hashCode(){ return x ^ y; }
}
```

then declare

```
Map<Pair, Integer> matrix = new HashMap<>();
```

to set value use

```
matrix.put(new Pair(x, y), value);
```

to get value use

```
int value = matrix.get(new Pair(x, y));
```

Comment: Any example how to do this?

Comment: Do what? Create `Pair` class?

Comment: How to create Pair class?

Comment: Use java.awt.Point.

Comment: @talex Please check my answer.

Comment: @ana123 Which answer?